# Importing package installed with pip3 causes ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package, python-imaging-library

I installed the **pillow 3.3.0** package for Python 3.5.2 Mac by using the **pip3 install statement** in terminal, it successfully downloaded and installed. (I did the same for other pacakges.)

When trying to call *import pillow*, following warning is displayed:

```
>>>import pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    from pillow import *
ImportError: No module named 'pillow'
```

*I took following steps:*

Those are the packages locally installed:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)

['numpy==1.11.1', 'pillow==3.3.0', 'pip==8.1.2', 'psycopg2==2.6.2', 'setuptools==20.10.1']
```

When pip3 installing pillow again, following warning shows up:

```
MyComputer-MBP-2:~ user$ pip3 install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Other packages work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importable name of the Pillow library is `PIL` because it is a fork of the original PIL. Just do

```
from PIL import *
```

Or even better, only import those names you actually need—see this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad).

Answer (score 0):

the package name is PIL

use

```
from PIL import *
```